# Tesseract OCR : Unsupported image type

Tags: macos, macports, homebrew, tesseract-ocr

*I converted the PDF to TIF file using the following commands on terminal*

`convert -density 300 -depth 4 lang.font-name.exp0.pdf lang.font-name.exp0.tif`

`convert lang.font-name.exp0.tif -colorspace rgb -type truecolor lang.font-name.exp0.tif`

*Then I tried to run `makebox` command,*

`tesseract lang.font-name.exp0.tif lang.font-name.exp0 batch.nochop makebox`

*which produced the following error:*

`Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.02.02 with Leptonica
Error in findTiffCompression: function not present
Error in pixReadStreamTiff: function not present
Error in pixReadStream: tiff: no pix returned
Error in pixRead: pix not read
Unsupported image type.`

*And assuming it is something related to the `libtiff`, ran command `tesseract -v` and found (or guessed) it to be missing*

`tesseract 3.02.02
leptonica-1.70
libjpeg 8d : libpng 1.6.10 : zlib 1.2.5`

***It produces the same thing even if i uninstall and reinstall lib tiff. Not sure what I'm missing here. Please advice!***

`brew rm -f libtiff
brew cleanup
brew missing
brew doctor
find /usr/local -user root
brew install libtiff`

Output Of command `brew info leptonica` [image: here]

**Edit #1**

Produced this tiff file using `GhostScript` which returns the same error when I try to run `makebox` command. Maybe there is something else I am missing? I set like 50+ as font size, is that fine?

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/97646145/Issue/Tiff_File.zip (~4 MB)

**Edit #2**

I created one page tif using `GhostScript`, even it isn't working??

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/97646145/Issue/Onepage_TIFF.zip (~60 KB)

Comment: really cool question!

Comment: @HarryMoreno Thank you! any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're following [Michael Lissner's post](http://michaeljaylissner.com/blog/adding-new-fonts-to-tesseract-3-ocr-engine) to add custom font to Tesseract.

I tried the same thing (the `convert` command) and got myself with a broken TIFF which couldn't be opened with any application.

So I chose the GUI alternative. I wrote my text in Scribus (because it allowed me to increase spacing between characters), then exported directly as TIFF from the **File** - **Export** - **Save as Image** menu. I chose a 300 DPI resolution.

What else you may try:

- GIMP opens PDFs which can be saved as TIFF
- Ghostscript: `gs -sDEVICE=tiffgray -r300x300 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sOutputFile=<image_file> <input_pdf>` (it converts all pages if it is the case)

What other problems you may encounter:

- Linux: if you installed the repo version of Tesseract (at least in Ubuntu) you won't have the required executables: `unicharset_extractor` and `mftraining` (or they're not in path, because the package should [include them](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/mftraining.1.html)).

Comment: That is exactly the same post I followed.. I would give it a try and let you know how it went! Thank you!

Comment: can you please check my updated question?

Comment: @Nina that's a 75 pages TIFF. I don't think it handles multipage.

Comment: So should I make it single page tif and try? @Cornelius
What if I want multipages tif?

Comment: @Nina don't know what to say. I recommend making 3 A4 TIFFs (one for regular, bold and italic) of 300 DPI grayscale. In my case it worked perfectly. Also the TIFFs weren't +600 MB size.

Comment: Thank you for the help Cornelius.. I would do as suggested and try my luck! Will mark your's as answer once I get it working for single page :) Thanks again!!

Comment: even single page tif isn't working for me :(

Comment: you could always whip up a bash script to batch all the pages. But yeah you need to get a single page working first.

Comment: @HarryMoreno Trying to make single page work..